# Bash script how to run condition "if" in looping "while" with a 10 minute time limit

Tags: bash, shell

Here I would like to make a Bash script where I would like to know whether an application is already listening to a port or not, by using the command `netstat`.

If the port was already listened to, then he bring up the results.

If not, script will repeat the `netstat` command with a 10-minute time limit, and if more than 10 minutes, command will not be executed, the result is an error.

If running manual `netstat` command in terminal:

```
netstat -atn | grep 8779
```

The results:

```
comp@yd:~$ erp-enterprise/bin$ netstat -atn | grep 8779
tcp6       0      0 :::8779                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

The following script that I have made, what's next?

```
#!/bin/bash 
NETSTAT=`netstat -ant | grep :::8779`

echo $NETSTAT
VAR_ERR="Port APP 8779, not listen !"
VAR_SUCS="Port APP 8779, LISTEN"

while [[ "$NETSTAT" = "" ]] ;
do
    echo $NETSTAT
    if [[ -z "$NETSTAT" ]];
    then
            echo $VAR_ERR
            NETSTAT=`netstat -ant | grep :::8082`
    else   
            echo $VAR_SUCS
            exit 0
done
echo $VAR_SUCS
```

If the application is not listening to the port, script will continue looping.

The results:

```
comp@yd:~$ ./listen_port.sh
Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !
```

If the application is already listening to the port, script will stop and eject results.

```
comp@yd:~$ ./listen_port.sh
Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8082, not listen !

Port APP 8779, LISTEN
```

How do I give a time limit for a script that stops?

Comment: Not sure *what* should have a time limit, but you could retry things in a loop until a certain amount of time has passed, or you could run a command with [`timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout).

Comment: Oh yes, sir .. but I tried to explain above, to showed my bash script, and how do I continue my script? how the addition of the script? so I mean that,sir

Comment: Do you want a timeout *within* the script or do you want to execute it with a timeout? (And please don't call me ‘sir’.)

Comment: Okay I want to give a time-out in the script, in its looping section @Biffen

Comment: Do you want the loop itself to stop, or do you want the call to `netstat` to have a timeout?

Comment: My needs, wants to call "netstat" but delay every 1 minutes. If looping the port has not also listen of up to 15 minutes gone, then the loop is forced to stop

Comment: It's fairly easy to make a loop stop (as in: not continue) after a certain amount of time. Is there anything you have tried that you can show us (otherwise this reads like a requirement specification rather than a question)? As for the delay; a simple `sleep` should do.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `timeout` command:

```
timeout 10m /path/to/your_script.sh
```

The above command will start `/path/to/your_script.sh` and terminate it after 10 minutes if it has not terminated on it's own.

Further read: [`man timeout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout)

Answer (score 2):

I like @hek2mgl's solution, but if you do want to do it within your script you could use the the [`SECONDS`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) variable to see how much time has passed.  So your loop could change the condition to something like

```
while [[ "$NETSTAT" = "" ]] && [[ $SECONDS -lt 600 ]];
```

or

```
while [[ -z "$NETSTAT" ]] && [[ $SECONDS -lt 600 ]];
```

to use the builtin test for whether a string is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from within the bash script not relying on other tools:

```
#! /bin/bash

trap 'echo "error after retrying for $secs"; exit 1' USR1

secs=600

{ sleep $secs; kill -s USR1 0; } &

while :
do
    netstat -ant | grep -q :::8082 && exit 0
    sleep 1
done
```